# get drawable from imageView - different references

Tags: android, imageview

I have created `MyDrawable`, a subclass of `Drawable` and I have set a `myDrawable` object into an `imageView`. When I try to access it with this code

```
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
Log.d(TAG, "imageView.getDrawable = " + drawable);
```

the Log shows me the reference `com.myPackage.ImageLoader.MyDrawable@xxxxxxxx`

Then I run an AsyncTask and I give it the imageView in input. Now, if from inside the AsyncTask I run the same code as above to get the drawable from the imageView, the Log shows me the reference `android.graphics.Drawable.BitmapDrawable@yyyyyyyy`

The two results are different and I have the problem that in the AsyncTask, the object `myDrawable` is not recognized as an instance of `MyDrawable` class. In particular the condition    `(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable)` is always false.

How to obtain the same reference (in particular the first one) for the object?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what object is logged as a BitmapDrawable?

Comment: If I create `Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();` in my ImageLoader class the result is a drawable with the reference `com.myPackage.ImageLoader.MyDrawable@xxxxxxxx` that IS instanceof myDrawable.

If I do the same - I create `Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();` - in an AsyncTask that should deal with the specific imageView, the result is a drawable with the reference `android.graphics.Drawable.BitmapDrawable@yyyyyyyy` that IS NOT instanceof myDrawable even if the imageView is the same

Comment: so in your AsyncTask you have one of ImageView.setImage*() call, check it

Comment: no because before executing the AsyncTask I do the following:

`BitmapDisplayerTask task = new BitmapDisplayerTask(imageView);
myDrawable myDrawable = new MyDrawable(task);
imageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);  
task.execute(imageID);`

where `BitmapDisplayerTask extends AsyncTask` and `MyDrawable` keeps reference to the task.

Since I have created the task giving in input the imageView I can access the imageView in the task with no problem but if I do `imageView.getDrawable();` the result is different depending if I am into or out the AyncTask.

Comment: if it can help, I am trying to reproduce this code: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html
but I don't understand why it doesn't work even if the code is pretty identical

Comment: and ypu say you dont have this: setImageBitmap(bitmap) ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have it but just before that I check if
`Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable(); if (drawable instanceof MyDrawable)` and this condition **in my AsyncTask** is always false so `setImageBitmap(bitmap)` is never executed. As I said, I think this is because the reference to the drawable is `android.graphics.Drawable.BitmapDrawable@yyyyyyyy` so a BitmapDrawable

Comment: So the only way to check who sets a BitmapDrawable is to extend ImageView and override its setImageDrawable